# Split (A/B) testing in Heroku?

Tags: testing, heroku, split, devops, ab-testing

I am seeking for a way to split test branches with Heroku exactly like Netlify:
https://docs.netlify.com/site-deploys/split-testing/#run-a-branch-based-test

Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: Typically you add a library for it. Then you either configure the A/B testing within the codebase itself or within a 3rd party platform. Either way, you need some level of integration within your heroku app itself, so it helps to know what language/framework you are using.

Comment: OK, I'm using React (nextjs). And I want to test branches not features within the same code!

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure that's wise lots of potential issues (mostly just requiring procedural solutions), but I imagine it's basically the same logic, You just redirect the user to a different deploy instead or query a different deploy server instead. IE: User lands on the master branch server. User has 60% chance of using the master branch server, 30% chance of using the branch B server, and 10% chance of using the branch C server. Standard A/B testing approaches apply to avoid getting the user into a bad state. If it's handled via AJAX the user won't even know they are using a branch deploy.